# php paging and the use of limit clause

Tags: php, pagination, limit

Imagine you got a 1m record table and you want to limit the search results down to say 10,000 and not more than that. So what do I use for that? Well, the answer is use the limit clause.

example

`select recid from mytable order by recid asc limit 10000`

This is going to give me the last 10,000 records entered into this table.

So far no paging. 
But the limit phrase is already in use.

That brings to question to the next level.

What if I want to page thru this record particular record set 100 recs at a time? Since the  `limit` phrase is already part of the original query, how do I use it again, this time to take care of the paging?

If the org. query did not have a limit clause to begin with, I'd adjust it as `limit 0,100` and then adjusting it as `limit 100,100` and then `limit 200,100` and so on while the paging takes it course. But at this time, I cannot.

You almost think you'd want to use two limit phrases one after the other - which is not not gonna work.

`limit 10000 limit 0,100` for sure it would error out.

So what's the solution in this particular case?

[EDIT]

After I post this question, I realized that the limit 10000 in the org. query becomes meaningless once the paging routine kicks in. I somehow confused myself and though that  `order by recid asc limit 10000` in its entirety is part of the where clause. In reality, the `limit 10000` portion has no bearing in the recordset content - other than taking care of the confining the recordset to the requested limit. So, there is no point of keeping the limit 10000 once the paging starts. I'm sorry for wasting your time with this. :(

Comment: Limit to 100 and make sure your offset is not bigger than 9900

Comment: How many records do you want in the result set returned by the query, in the end?

Comment: To all: I think I had a logical fallacy in my question. Practically speaking, the limit 10000 that the org query had becomes meaningless once the paging routine kicks in. Remember I got a `limit 10000` to begin with. I will add this observation to the question so that I make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say get rid of the first limit, then don't bother doing a count of the table, or take the lesser of the count and your limit, i.e. 10000, and do the pagination based on that.

i.e.

```
$perpage = 100;
$pages = $totalcount/$perpage;
$page = $get['Page'];
if($page > $pages || $page < 0)
{
     $page = 0;
}
$limit = "LIMIT " . ($page * $perpage) . ", " . $perpage;
```

To calculate totalcount, do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable
```

then check it against your limit, i.e.

```
if($totalcount > 10000)
{
    $totalcount = 10000;
}
```

The reason to do a dedicated count query is that it requires very little DB to PHP data transfer, and many DBMS's can optimize the crap out of it compared to a full table SELECT query.

Comment: how do you compute the $totalcount? When the paging takes place, the adjusted SQL would be something like `select recid from mytable order by recid asc limit 400,100`. In this case, mysql would return the recordset number of rows as 100, a number which is always equal to the paging record count. Do I have to make two queries? (first one without any `limit`ation to get the correct number of rows and second one to actually enforce the offset? I would need the total count to decide when to show the next/prev links and when not to.

Comment: In the mean time, I visited the http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm and there I do see that the same query runs twice back to back, exactly like I commented, one to get the number of rows, one to do the display. I come from ASP background and in ASP, we got a concept called moving the recordset cursor. Instead of running the same query again, wouldn't I be better off sticking to the one that compiles the whole thing and get the correct number of rows and then in the while loop, just skip the ones that are already shown and breakout that is beyond the current window?

Comment: edited already, but no, I wouldn't recommend that personally.  Running the same query twice is wasteful, and a cursor like that is expensive compared to asking the DBMS for exactly the rows you want.

Comment: Well Andrew, if your original query takes a heck of a time or a very expensive one, regardless of whether you fetch a single col or multiple, the little select count with the same where is the same as running the query twice.

Comment: Well, you said MySQL, and it doesn't support scrollable cursors, so your stuck with what I said or fetching and throwing away up to 9900 rows of data.  What you need to think about now is caching.  Does that query change row counts every second? or can you cache $totalcount in a users session?  In addition, have you tested it?  MySQL, and in fact most dbms's, relies on caching to speed up query execution, so most likely the second query would take a fraction of the time of the first one.

Comment: Good points... I was thinking of computing the total count only on first time around (when the query string is free of paging info ) and then keep passing it in the QS. That would avoid the use of sessions as well as avoiding the running the main query at every page load.

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT can have two arguments, the first being the offset and the second being how many records to return. So

```
LIMIT 5,10
```

Will skip the first 5 records then fetch the next 10.

You will have to set your limit based on the current page. Something like

```
LIMIT (CURRENT_PAGE  -1) * PAGE_SIZE , PAGE_SIZE
```

So if you had ten records per page and were on page 2 you would skip the first ten records and grab the next ten.

Answer (score 1):

The offset suggestion is a great one and you should probably use that. But if for some reason offset doesn't fit your needs (say someone inserting a new record would shift your page slightly) you could also add a where recid > #### clause to your query. This is how you would paginate when working with Twitter API.

Here is an example in PHP.

```
    <?php
        $query = 'select recid from mytable';
        if(isset($_GET['recid'])&&$_GET['recid']!=''){
            $query = $query.' where recid > '.$_GET['recid'];
        }
        $query = $query.' order by recid asc limit 10000';

        //LOG INTO MYSQL

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $last_id = '';

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             //DO YOUR DISPLAY WORK
             $last_id = $row['recid'];
        }

        echo '<a href="?recid='.$last_id.'>Next Page</a>';
   ?>
```

Again, a bit more complicated than needs to be but will return set pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offset variable. If this is your full query then You could use:

```
select recid from mytable order by recid asc limit 100 offset 300
```

for example would give you from 300-399.  And obviously you will increase the offset by 100 for every page.  So for the first page offset =0, for the second page offset = 100, etc.

to be general offset = (page-1)*100

And as @Mathieu Lmbert said you can make sure the offset doesn't reach 9900.

Comment: What do you mean it will not work?  I have limit 100 offset 300 as an example.  note I have limit 100 not 10000.

Answer (score -2):

Effectively there can be only one limit, and it must be in the query. So the only solution will be to adjust the LIMIT clause in your query.

The thing you shouldn't do is to read all 10.000 entries, throwing away the 9900 that you do not want.

Comment: Fetching 10,000 records and discarding 9,900 is a horrible idea.

Comment: What if the LIMIT 10000 clause cannot be easily removed from the query?